# Port forwarding from OpenVPN Client to Public Internet

Tags: iptables, firewall, openvpn, routing, port-forwarding

I need to forward port 44444 of my VPN client to the public internet with my public IP on port 44444, how i can do this?

The VPN Server is mine and I have root access.

Example how i can do this?
WANIP:44444-> 172.27.224.2:44444 (VPN LOCAL IP) ?

I'm trying with this but no success:

```
sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d WANIP -p tcp --dport 44444 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.27.224.2:44444
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -d 172.27.224.2 -p tcp --dport 44444 -j SNAT --to-source WANIP
```

Interface of WAN IP is eth0 and Interface of VPN LOCAL IP is as0t0

Comment: Did you also ACCEPT the packet itself (`iptables -A INPUT -m tcp -p tcp -d WANIP --dport 4444 -J ACCEPT`)? And did you also ACCEPT the forwarding of the packets (`iptables -A FORWARD -j ACCEPT -p tcp --dport 44444 -d WANIP -m state --state NEW`)? I used [this manual](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-forward-ports-through-a-linux-gateway-with-iptables) for setting up similar things as you want to archive .. maybe it helps you to find a solution

Comment: Very at the bottom there is a quite complete example setup